# How to get contact list from ejabbered server

Tags: android, client-server, ejabberd, smack, asmack

Hi i am able to connect and chat using ejabbered server. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.blikoon.com/tutorials/android-smack-xmpp-introductionbuilding-a-simple-client)
 for smack api and i am using

> compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0-alpha6'

i searched on internet for this but so far not able to get the list of online users from own server.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this as Admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i am able to get rid of this problem

in **ContactModel.java** class i added

```
Roster roster = RoosterConnection.mConnection.getRoster();
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
```

here `RoosterConnection.mConnection` is `XMPPTCPConnection` 
In the version 4.1.0 method of getting Roster is bit changed. Hope it will be helpful for others. Here is the official [documentation/ update-guide link](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.1-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide)